# Override all keys of an object but its id

Tags: javascript

I have a similar object as this one but it has quite more keys. I want to update all of its keys but id. I can do so manually. But I think it is not the best way.

```js
const o = {
  name: "unknow",
  key: "key"
  value: "value"
  id ": 12
}
```

---

#### How can I update/override all keys of an object but id?

## Update

The two object has the same keys. But their keys have different value. I need to update all keys of the first object excluding its id.

Comment: @Marcel I do not want to merge. Its not dup

Comment: if your two objects have the same keys but id, simply use `o = {...o, ...otherObject}`

Comment: @Marcel, I don't this OP mentioned anywhere in the question that he wants to merge two objects. As per my understandings he just wants to go through the single object keys while skipping `ìd` only.

Comment: Don 't get me wrong and I appologize if I was wrong. The TO said exactly `I want to update all of its keys but id`. Overwriting one objects properties with another objects properties is merging. Just unset the id property of the object you want to merge with and voilá! The first mentioned objects properties will be overwritten with the second mentioned objects propoerties. This is merging. Merging does exactly what the TO wants. Updating the properties from the first given object with the second given object properties.

Comment: @Marcel I believe that you're mistaken: *merging* may involve immutability, thus, you would get a new object.

Comment: Well, if it matters that merging is creating a new object with the wanted result ...

Comment: @Marcel I need to keep the value of the first object id.  Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2, obj3, etc);  does not do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you're looking for something like `assignBut`: it sets properties of `ob` on `oa` but the specified one:

```js
const assignBut = (prop, oa, ob) => {
  for (let key of Object.keys(ob))
    // Check that I also verify that the property
    // to set should be part of "oa" object. This
    // prevents adding new properties: it just updates 
    // existing ones.
    if (key !== prop && oa.hasOwnProperty(key))
      oa[key] = ob[key]
}

const oa = {
  name: "unknow",
  key: "key",
  value: "value",
  id: 12
}

const ob = {
  name: "xxx",
  key: "yyy",
  value: "zzz",
  other: "aaa",
  yetAnother: 289,
  id: 15
}

assignBut('id', oa, ob)

console.log(oa)
```

### Another approach to omit a given property

One may take advantage of destructuring and computed property names to omit the whole given property so the `for..of` just needs to check that each property from `ob` is present in `oa` to set it.

Also, one may save the check to verify that a property from `ob` exists in `oa` performing an intersection of `oa` and `ob` keys:

```js
const oa = {
  name: "unknow",
  key: "key",
  value: "value",
  id: 12
}

const ob = {
  name: "xxx",
  key: "yyy",
  value: "zzz",
  other: "aaa",
  yetAnother: 289,
  id: 15
}

const intersect = (xs, ys) => xs.filter(x => ys.includes(x))

const assignBut = (prop, oa, {
  [prop]: omitted,
  ...ob
}) => {
  const sharedKeys = intersect(Object.keys(oa), Object.keys(ob))

  for (let key of sharedKeys)
    oa[key] = ob[key]
}

assignBut('id', oa, ob)

console.log(oa)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) like below -

```js
const o = {
      name: "unknow",
      key: "key",
      value: "value",
      id : 12
    };
    
    Object.keys(o).forEach((key)=>{
      if(key !=="id"){
         console.log(o[key]) //value
      }
     }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Following approach is based on lodash. If you are not comfortable using a library, please ignore.

Benefit of `omit` is that you can pass an array of keys and ignore multiple keys.

There is also a function called `pick` where you can only pick certain properties you need.

#### _.omit

```js
const o = { name: "unknow", key: "key", value: "value", id: 12 }
const props = { name: "foo", key: "key2", value: "bar", id: 15 };

const final = _.assign({}, o, _.omit(props, 'id'));

console.log(final)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

#### _.pick

```js
const o = { name: "unknow", key: "key", value: "value", id: 12 }
const props = { name: "foo", key: "key2", value: "bar", id: 15, test: 'abc', hello: 'world' };

const final = _.assign({}, o, _.pick(props, ['name', 'key', 'value']));

console.log(final)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

#### pure js implementation

```js
const o = { name: "unknow", key: "key", value: "value", id: 12 }
const propsOmit = { name: "foo", key: "key2", value: "bar", id: 15 };
const propsPick = { name: "foo", key: "key2", value: "bar", id: 15, test: 'abc', hello: 'world' };

const finalOmit = Object.assign({}, o, omit(propsOmit, 'id'));
const finalPick = Object.assign({}, o, omit(propsPick, ['id', 'test', 'hello']));

console.log(finalOmit)
console.log(finalPick)

function omit(obj, ignoreKeys) {
  if (!Array.isArray(ignoreKeys)) {
    ignoreKeys = [ ignoreKeys ];
  }
  
  const copy = Object.assign({}, obj);
  ignoreKeys.forEach((k) => delete copy[k]);
  return copy;
}

function pick(obj, selectKeys) {
  if (!Array.isArray(selectKeys)) {
    selectKeys = [ selectKeys ];
  }
  
  const copy = {};
  ignoreKeys.forEach((k) => copy[k] = obj[k]);
  return copy;
}
```

#### References:

- [_.assign](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#assign)
- [_.omit](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omit)
- [_.pick](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick)

Comment: **Note:** I know, question is not tagged with `lodash` and answering on it without consent, but this is an alternate approach and a caveat has been added.